# Visual studio connect to postgres database using entity framework and npgsql

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am trying to connect my .NET project to a postgres database using entity framework 6 in Visual Studio 2019. I'm the getting the error:

> unable to find the requested .net framework data provider. it may not
> be installed.
> or the window just closes and nothing happens

These are the steps I took:

1 - Installed the npgsql extension to visual studio version 4.1.3.1 (I think this is the latest one available)

2 - Installed the npgsql nuget package from the package manager Version 4.1.3.1

3 - nuget package entityframework6 version 6.4.0

4 - nuget package entityframework6.npgsql version 6.4.0

5 - my web.config has the neccessary line:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
  <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

6 - On the server explorer, when I try to add a connection I am able to choose Postgres Database as a datasource

[image]

7 - When i try to type anything into the boxes to enter the server information it automatically closes the window and doesn't continue

[image]

I've also tried adding it thru the Server Explorer. The same thing happened when and I get the error

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?